# R package installation error (dbarts compiling error)

Tags: r, c, gfortran

when I installed the dbarts package from the source, the compiling process reported some error information, as below. Please help me with this issue. thank you in advance

```
> remotes::install_github("vdorie/dbarts")
Downloading GitHub repo vdorie/dbarts@HEAD
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/sj/jdgnsm9n14vgsjctfrk5x2_80000gn/T/Rtmp0RD83w/remotes12c447f59f6e2/vdorie-dbarts-d61b38c/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘dbarts’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  running ‘cleanup’
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (437ms)
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘dbarts_0.9-23.tar.gz’
   
* installing *source* package ‘dbarts’ ...
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 accepts -g... yes
checking for aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -E
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp accepts -g... yes
checking for aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -E
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... no
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin23.0.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin23.0.0
checking for C compiler vendor... gnu
checking whether C compiler accepts ... yes
checking for arm_neon.h... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking whether aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 is Clang... no
checking whether pthreads work with "-pthread" and "-lpthread"... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking whether more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
checking for cstdint... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for malloc.h... no
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking size of size_t... 8
checking alignment of void*... 8
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for ffs... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for working posix_memalign... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking if g++ supports namespace std... yes
checking whether snprintf is in std::... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking whether log1p is in std::... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating src/config.hpp
config.status: creating src/dbarts/config.hpp
config.status: creating src/misc/config.h
config.status: creating src/external/config.h
config.status: creating inst/include/dbarts/types.hpp
config.status: creating src/include/misc/types.h
** libs
using C compiler: ‘aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0’
using C++ compiler: ‘aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c R_C_interface.cpp -o R_C_interface.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c R_interface.cpp -o R_interface.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c R_interface_common.cpp -o R_interface_common.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c R_interface_crossvalidate.cpp -o R_interface_crossvalidate.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c R_interface_rbart.cpp -o R_interface_rbart.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c R_interface_sampler.cpp -o R_interface_sampler.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c crossvalidate.cpp -o crossvalidate.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c guessNumCores.cpp -o guessNumCores.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c makeModelMatrixFromDataFrame.c -o makeModelMatrixFromDataFrame.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c bartFit.cpp -o bartFit.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c binaryIO.cpp -o binaryIO.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c birthDeathRule.cpp -o birthDeathRule.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c changeRule.cpp -o changeRule.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c functions.cpp -o functions.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c likelihood.cpp -o likelihood.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c node.cpp -o node.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c parameterPrior.cpp -o parameterPrior.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c state.cpp -o state.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c swapRule.cpp -o swapRule.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c tree.cpp -o tree.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-c++-13 -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../../inst/include -I../include  -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c treePrior.cpp -o treePrior.o
ar rv ../dbarts.a bartFit.o binaryIO.o birthDeathRule.o changeRule.o functions.o likelihood.o node.o parameterPrior.o state.o swapRule.o tree.o treePrior.o
ar: creating archive ../dbarts.a
a - bartFit.o
a - binaryIO.o
a - birthDeathRule.o
a - changeRule.o
a - functions.o
a - likelihood.o
a - node.o
a - parameterPrior.o
a - state.o
a - swapRule.o
a - tree.o
a - treePrior.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c io.c -o io.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c randomBase.c -o randomBase.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c randomNorm.c -o randomNorm.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c random.c -o random.o
ar rv ../external.a io.o randomBase.o randomNorm.o random.o
ar: creating archive ../external.a
a - io.o
a - randomBase.o
a - randomNorm.o
a - random.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC  -c adaptiveRadixTree.c -o adaptiveRadixTree.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c binaryIO.c -o binaryIO.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c blockingThreadManager.c -o blockingThreadManager.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c hierarchicalThreadManager.c -o hierarchicalThreadManager.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c linearAlgebra.c -o linearAlgebra.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c moments.c -o moments.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c partition.c -o partition.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c simd.c -o simd.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c string.c -o string.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c thread.c -o thread.o
echo aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c linearAlgebra_neon.c -o linearAlgebra_neon.c
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread -I/opt/R/arm64/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp -fPIC -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2 -fPIC -c linearAlgebra_neon.c -o linearAlgebra_neon.c
echo aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread  -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -fPIC -c partition_neon.c -o partition_neon.o
aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 -arch arm64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../include -pthread -I/opt/R/arm64/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -fopenmp -fPIC -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2 -fPIC -c partition_neon.c -o partition_neon.o
partition_neon.c: In function 'vmovemask_u8':
partition_neon.c:16:3: note: use '-flax-vector-conversions' to permit conversions between vectors with differing element types or numbers of subparts
   16 |   uint8x16_t vmask = vandq_u8(input, vdupq_n_u8(0x80));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:16:31: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vandq_u8'
   16 |   uint8x16_t vmask = vandq_u8(input, vdupq_n_u8(0x80));
      |                               ^~~~~
      |                               |
      |                               uint16x8_t
In file included from ../include/misc/intrinsic.h:9,
                 from partition_neon.c:8:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/include/arm_neon.h:1120:22: note: expected 'uint8x16_t' but argument is of type 'uint16x8_t'
 1120 | vandq_u8 (uint8x16_t __a, uint8x16_t __b)
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
partition_neon.c:19:27: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'vshlq_u8'
   19 |   vmask = vshlq_u8(vmask, vshift);
      |                           ^~~~~~
      |                           |
      |                           uint8x16_t
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/include/arm_neon.h:21084:37: note: expected 'int8x16_t' but argument is of type 'uint8x16_t'
21084 | vshlq_u8 (uint8x16_t __a, int8x16_t __b)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from partition_neon.c:29:
partition_body.c: In function 'misc_partitionRange_neon':
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:173:30: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  173 |     lh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(lh_comp);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:175:30: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  175 |     rh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(rh_comp);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:181:34: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  181 |         lh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(lh_comp);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:187:34: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  187 |         rh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(rh_comp);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from partition_neon.c:37:
partition_body.c: In function 'misc_partitionIndices_neon':
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:255:30: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  255 |     lh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(lh_comp);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:257:30: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  257 |     rh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(rh_comp);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:263:34: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  263 |         lh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(lh_comp);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
partition_body.c:147:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmovemask_u8'
  147 | #  define movemask(_X_) vmovemask_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(_X_))
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |
      |                                      __Uint8x16_t
partition_body.c:269:34: note: in expansion of macro 'movemask'
  269 |         rh_mask = (unsigned int) movemask(rh_comp);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
partition_neon.c:12:29: note: expected 'uint16x8_t' but argument is of type '__Uint8x16_t'
   12 | int vmovemask_u8(uint16x8_t input)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
make[1]: *** [partition_neon.o] Error 1
make: *** [sublibs] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dbarts’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/dbarts’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/dbarts’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/sj/jdgnsm9n14vgsjctfrk5x2_80000gn/T//Rtmp0RD83w/file12c441f8f3901/dbarts_0.9-23.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

when I installed the dbarts package from the source, the compiling process reported some error information, as below. Please help me with this issue. thank you in advance

Comment: Since this is package-specific it may be worth putting an issue on the github repo. When I had a similar issue on linux it was mostly due to missing fortran on my system.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:gfortran]? The error comes from compiling a C source file.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, the aarch64-apple-darwin23-gcc-13 was set as a compiler, which is part of gfortran installed by Brew. I am not sure whether my understanding is right.

Comment: I have made a trial and error. finally, I added -flax-vector-conversions to CC compiler and got the package installed.